# Django shell not printing QuerySet

Tags: python, django

In the command prompt I have to enter the same text as the book 'python crash course' on page 393.  But my terminal is not giving the query set as it does in the book.

I enter:
`>>> t.entry_set.all()`

I get back:
`<QuerySet [<Entry: Entry object (1)>, <Entry: Entry object (2)>]>`

Comment: Did you implement a `__str__` method on your `Entry` model?

Comment: As @WillemVanOnsem mentioned you may also be missing the ```__str__``` method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#str

Comment: So I set up the __str__ method on the Entry model as it is explained in the book.  As well as the following info from the previews pages so that the entries have info in them.

Answer (score 0):

`t.entry_set.all()` will simply return a QuerySet object

To actually see the data you'll need to iterate through it

```
for entry in t.entry_set.all():
   print(entry.some_attribute)
```

Comment: this is done in the commande prompt?  if I have 2 querysets how do I enter that as the some_attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
t.entry_set.all().values()
```

It will give Queryset in the form of dictionary.

Comment: Thanks.  That gave all of the info for each but the book says that t.entry_set.all() should give the querysets with the info ellipsis no longer than 50 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure , you have mistake in indent in `models.py` . For example in the code below Class `Entry` is the main class, therefore Class `Meta` is Entry's subclass . 
 The same is for `def__str__(self)`

```py
class Entry(models.Model):
   class Meta:
       ...

   def __str__(self):
       ...
``
```